# Auth0 breaks Next.js -- pageProps are empty when page is wrapped with withPageAuthRequired HOC

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, auth0

#### Describe the problem

`pageProps` supplied via `getServerSideProps` object is empty when using `withPageAuthRequired`. I know I must be missing something basic as this must be an extremely common use case.

#### What was the expected behavior?

I expect that when I call `getServerSideProps`, I should receive the `pageProps` parameter in my functions `render` call. However, `pageProps` is an empty object `{}`. `getServerSideProps` is called, but when the component renders, its props are missing.

#### Reproduction

Step 1 - Create custom _app for UserProvider.

```js
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
export default (AdminApp)
```

Step 2 - Create a simple page (e.g. `Manage`) wrapped in withPageAuthRequired HOC.

```js
function Manage(props) { // <-- props is missing `data` attribute.
  return (
      <span>hello {props.data.siteTitle}</span>
  );
}

export default withPageAuthRequired(Manage);
```

Step 3 - Provide `pageProps` to the custom app via `getServerSideProps`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const websiteData = await getWebsiteData();

  return {
    props: {data: websiteData}
  }
}
```

Notice that in step 2, the props is not actually supplied with data from step 3. This only happened when I added auth0 to next.js.

#### Environment

**Version of this library used:**
`next@10.0.7`
`@auth0/nextjs-auth0@1.2.0`

Comment: Can you clarify on what file is your `getServerSideProps` declared? Is it on the `_app` page or `Manage` page?

Comment: @juliomalves it's in the `Manage` page. However, I've solved the issue. The problem was I am dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes this is embarrassing.  Turns out I wasn't properly passing the props to the component from the `_app` file.

```js
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Component /> {/*WHOOPS!*/}
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
export default (AdminApp)
```

I tried everything I could think of and must've forgotten to put that back :(